Контекст функции и список
Почему аргумент x:list функции сохраняет предыдущий вызов, если явно контекст должен быть удален после завершения работы
def foo(x=[]):
    x.append(1)
    return x

print(foo())
print(foo())


Это фича Питона. Коллекции в дефолтных аргументах инициализируются один раз - когда интерпретатор читает определения функций. При вызовах функций инициализация дефолтных аргументов уже не происходит, в отличие от других языков программирования. Поэтому происходит накопление. Это просто нужно знать.

Откуда следует вывод: не используйте изменяемые значения в качестве значений по умолчанию в  параметрах функций.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Смотря какое поведение нужно. Если нужно именно такое, какое оно в питоне, то почему бы и не использовать его )  Но если нужно как в других языках, то да, использовать None.

@CrazyElf, значение по-умолчанию в Питоне - фактически глобальная переменная. Нужна изменяющаяся глобальная переменная - так и её и надо так объявлять. А это свойство - очень сомнительного свойства.

А вообще это явно дубликат, сто раз обсуждалось, хорошо бы найти вопрос-первоисточник и пометить дубликатом.
